# Which Universities admit CS graduates for their theoretical physics course?

Tags: phd, graduate-admissions, mathematics, masters, physics

Hello am currently an undergraduate student. My major is CSE. But I am very much interested to do my masters and then PhD in theoretical physics/mathematical physics. Is there any university that admits CS graduates for these courses?
I have looked up some universities that offer these courses.
Queen Mary University, University of Edinburgh and Durham University sounds perfect to me (I can meet their minimum requirements).
But I am not sure whether they admit CS graduates or not. I have not got any reply from them yet. 
Would you suggest some Universities both in the UK and US that do? Would any university admit me directly for PhD (without masters)? Will having research paper help?
I could not find any university in the US that offer this course for masters.

Answer (score 0):

I can't speak for the UK, which has a different educational system altogether, but in the US, most programs would find a CS graduate "acceptable" for a physics doctorate. This assumes a good record overall, of course, and probably a few physics courses in which you did well. In the US, a CS student probably has a few such courses, though not advanced ones.

But to actually be admitted you have to be better than "acceptable".

In the US, the graduate program has quite a few courses available, primarily to prepare the student for comprehensive exams. But the normal path would be into a doctoral program, perhaps with an MS along the way.

I would guess that in the UK the university would expect an applicant to be further along in the major subject, but others would need to verify.

Comment: If I have research experience and research papers published will it help? Say I have works in computational quantum physics. Will it help?

Comment: Everything positive helps. But research experience in the field should help a lot. But the important judgements will come from an admissions committee that looks at your overall record.

Comment: I have an average profile academically. My cgpa is around 3 out of 4. Will it reduce my chance significantly?

Comment: The papers will help slightly, but I would still be strongly concerned about your ability to handle both the math and the physics involved in grad school physics courses.  The B average (3.0/4.0) is not a good sign either, given that a typical physics jock thinks CS is already an easy sledding.

Comment: To be honest I was pretty good in maths and physics back in highschool. And I enjoyed them. I was never comfortable with CSE. That's why I wanted to try out physics again. And was looking for taught physics courses like those ones at University of Edinburgh or other UK universities. But UK universities have strict prerequisites unlike US universities so I am not quite sure about whether or not they will accept someone from a different background. So I was looking for masters program at the US. But I may have to reconsider it.

Answer (score -2):

In my experience, you would have to be very unusual to make this jump.  Of course it's possible.  I have seen it more from chemistry to physics or math to physics for students who knew they just sort of picked wrong to start.  Even then the road was not easy.  (But consider Lars Onsanger was a chemE bachelors.  However, he was also Lars Onsanger!)

In general, CS students are much less mathematically strong than physics students, so you would have to show this is not true. It's not even about specific courses (although that helps), but about a strong ability with "engineering mathematics" (Bessel functions out the yingyang, long derivations and homework problems with lots of algebra).

There's also the matter of maybe not knowing the physics.  Physics students sort of follow a plan of learning the same topic with more intensity (usually with new mathematical structures added) over time.  Consider that mechanics is tought as in intro course (similar to all students), than as a junior level majors course, than in grad school.  Same for E&M.  Quantum mechanics and stat mech (in grad school) are taught at a level harder than that during junior year majors course.  I.e. it's helpful to have had it before if you don't want to get killed.

Again, if you're a genius, it really doesn't matter.  But if you're just above average, I would be concerned about the pre-reqs.  Not for any silly reasons of credentials but just for the grounding.  I mean Jackson E&M is not trivial and many physics grad students struggle with it.  If you're anything like the average CS student as opposed to the average physics student (in terms of math and problem solving ability), I would recommend going nowhere near a physics grad program.  Even if you got accepted, you'd struggle and the experience would not be good for you.

P.s.  Finally to address your question specifically, I recommend to reach out to the departments.  You will learn more than just coming to a Q&A site.  Talk to them and learn something.  I suspect, they will actually be more willing to consider out of track people than you think.  But they will expect you to be rather special.  And you may get a few grim old salts like me, who warn you.

P.s.s.  Also, consider that the market for physics Ph.D.s is pretty dismal and has been for about 30+ years.  Many of them eventually go into some sort of computer related work since there's just so many jobs for that sort of stuff and since they have the physics brain to rely on to just get up to speed on the computer stuff.

Comment: The job market is the only reason for me to choose CSE. But unfortunately I never felt comfortable with it.

Comment: Sorry, but you are trying to argue that "your sense" about the general case applies to an individual. Neither fair nor valid.